# CSS draggable navigation without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT: I included a js fiddle link below

I am trying to create a navigation bar for a website where if you visit it with a small screen the navigation bar is not collapsible but it is absolute and you'll just need to grab and slide it left and right without sliding the whole page but the `div` only for the navigation bar. It is creating a scrollbar horizontally which it should not as i am wanting.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});

$(function() {
  var curDown = false,
    curYPos = 0,
    curXPos = 0;
  $(window).mousemove(function(m) {
    if (curDown === true) {
      $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + (curYPos - m.pageY));
      $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + (curXPos - m.pageX));
    }
  });

  $(window).mousedown(function(m) {
    curDown = true;
    curYPos = m.pageY;
    curXPos = m.pageX;
  });

  $(window).mouseup(function() {
    curDown = false;
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

header {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

#strip {
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 17px;
  width: 100%;
}

#company_name {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 12px;
}

.nav {
  margin-right: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  user-select: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav ul {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.nav ul>li {
  display: table-cell;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #99999F;
}

.nav ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #99999F;
}

.nav ul>.active {
  display: block;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #99999F;
  color: #00A97E;
}

.nav ul>.active>a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #99999F;
  color: #00A97E;
}

.padded-underline {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#user_nav {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  float: right;
}

#user_nav>ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#user_nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <div id="strip">
    <img src="images/user-icon.png" style="width: 30px; margin-left: 20px"><span id="company_name">MDA Media Development APAC</span>
    <div id="user_nav">
      <ul>
        <li>Admin x44 | Profile</li>
        <li>Sample Link</li>
        <li>Logout</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <div id="myNavbar">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
        <hr style="margin-top: -4px; margin-right: 50px" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<!-- <input type="text"> -->
```

I am not used on developing the front-end that's why i am having trouble around here. But i have no choice even though i am not a designer i still want to make the site look modern.

Thanks a lot!

Reference for grabbing the div that i am using:
https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/uzGvy

EDIT:

JS Fiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/6878pnLn/

Comment: Post a working snippet

Comment: Do you mean like at JS Fiddle?

Comment: Yes but a better choice is the SO snippet, it's an instrument on the bar when you write answers and questions

Comment: I included a link now sir kindly check. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No longer works

Answer (score 1):

`overflow-x: hidden` on the navigation bar wrapper should do the trick if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: I've already tried this but this doesn't stop from scrolling the whole body. My list is so big that it overlaps my design which is what i want but i also want to be able to scroll that specific div (id="nav") only not including the whole body when i drag.

Comment: Kindly check the JS Fiddle link i included. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify; you want to drag-and-drop scroll both the body, and the navigation bar?

Comment: Only the navigation bar. It's okay now i found a solution i'll post it if anyone wants. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Please do. Always nice to have the solution available if people run into the same issue :) Awesome the you managed to fix it yourself!

Comment: Also your answer helped me figuring out the answer so thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad I could be of some help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I specified the javascript i found at the internet to only point on the DIV i am trying to modify. Sorry if i didn't tried to understand the javascript first and then i've hidden the navigation bar scrollbar which was answered  @Christer Olsen. Hope this would be able to help anyone!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.js">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<style>

    body {
        margin: 0;
        /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
    }

    header {
        background-color: #F8F8F8;
    }

    #strip {
        height: 60px;
        padding-top: 17px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #company_name {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding-left: 12px;
    }

    .nav {
        margin-right: 100px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: -webkit-grab;
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        user-select: none;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .nav ul {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

    .nav ul > li {
        display: table-cell;
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #99999F;
    }

    .nav ul > li > a {
        display: block;
        margin-right: 15px;
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #99999F;
    }

    .nav ul > .active {
        display: block;
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-decoration-color: #99999F;
        color: #00A97E;
    }

    .nav ul > .active > a {
        display: block;
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-decoration-color: #99999F;
        color: #00A97E;
    }

    .padded-underline {
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }

    #user_nav {
        font-family: Segoe UI;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 2px;
        margin-right: 150px;
        float: right;
    }

    #user_nav > ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    #user_nav > ul > li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="strip">
            <img src="images/user-icon.png" style="width: 30px; margin-left: 20px"><span id="company_name">MDA Media Development APAC</span>
            <div id="user_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>Admin x44 | Profile</li>
                    <li>Sample Link</li>
                    <li>Logout</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div id="myNavbar">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ACCOUNTS</a></li>
                    <hr style="margin-top: -4px; margin-right: 50px" />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- <input type="text"> -->
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    });

    $(function(){
      var curDown = false,
          curYPos = 0,
          curXPos = 0;
      $(".nav").mousemove(function(m){
        if(curDown === true){
         $(".nav").scrollTop($(".nav").scrollTop() + (curYPos - m.pageY)); 
         $(".nav").scrollLeft($(".nav").scrollLeft() + (curXPos - m.pageX));
        }
      });

      $(".nav").mousedown(function(m){
        curDown = true;
        curYPos = m.pageY;
        curXPos = m.pageX;
      });

      $(".nav").mouseup(function(){
        curDown = false;
      });
    })

</script>
```